# Delete row of input by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delete-row, arr

Hi  in laravel I am storing values as an array then I retrieved them to update them I have this view:
[image]

what I want?
I want the user to be able to delete the row  of inputs by the use of JavaScript?
for exmple:
Dimpa, counting 2020 by one click in remove

What I Done?

this is my view code in Laravel:

```
 <?php
    $degress=json_decode($con->otheredu);
    $years=json_decode($con->othery);
    $Specializations=json_decode($con->othersp);
    $r= count($degress);


$i=0;

$p=0;
$o=0;
?>        
                        
<div class="remove">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4">
@foreach($degress as $degree)

<?php  
$id=$i++;
?>  
<input class="form-control"  value="{{$degree}}" id="degree{{$id}}"    placeholder="Enter your edution degree "     maxlength="125" name=otheredu[] type="text">
@endforeach
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4">
@foreach($Specializations as $Specialization)

<?php  
$cod=$p++
?>  
<input class="form-control"  value="{{$Specialization}}" id="Specialization{{$cod}}"    placeholder="Enter your Specialization "   required maxlength="125" name=othersp[] type="text">
@endforeach
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4">
@foreach($years as $year)
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10">

<?php  
$yearid=$o++
?>  
<input class="form-control"  value="{{$year}}" id="year{{$yearid}}"    placeholder="Enter your Specialization "     maxlength="125" name=othery[] type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">

<a class="bg-dark" onclick = "fun()"  class="remove_button" id = "btn">
remove
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
                                    </div>
```

I used this script:

```
function fun(){
     
    <?php  
$yearid=$o++
?> 
    document.getElementById("year{{$yearid}}").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("degree{{$yearid}}").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("Specialization{{$yearid}}").style.display = "none";}
 
</script>
```

there are two problems with it , it is not removed from database even when I removed the field
the other problem  it is only shows the id of fifth one and it is not working except when I change it  year{{$yearid}} to year0

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish this. One way is to use javascript fetch to submit the ID to the PHP to remove from the database, then use javascript to hide the row.

Comment: Can you give me   an eample or totrial?